# Having trouble opening a file in python using open()

Tags: python

I wanted to work on opening files so I tried running this code, no file opened up.

```
f =  open('Basic wx python window')
```

Comment: Do you have a file named `'Basic wx python window'`?

Comment: yes. That is why I'm so confused. Will python only open certain types of files.

Comment: No ... python can open any type of files although you might want to specify the file type as `'rb'` (`b` for binary)

Comment: Are you in the same directory as that file? If you don't specify the path, python must be executing in the same folder.

Comment: You say "no file opened up" but what did happen? Do you get an exception? If so, please include the full traceback in the question. If something else happens, please describe it.

Comment: Did you expect some sort of visible thing to happen, like a window appearing or something? `open` doesn't mean "launch some program to deal with the file" or anything like that. When you open a file, you receive an object representing the file that you can then read from. That's all.

Comment: I apologize that is what I thought open meant. How do I actually read the file. I'm very new to python.

Comment: To iterate over the lines, use `for line in f:`. To just get a big string representing the contents, use `f.read()`. To parse the contents as CSV or JSON or something, read the documentation for the [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) or [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or other appropriate module.

Comment: The official tutorial has a nice section on [Reading and Writing Files](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) that explains all of this.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I had to read() the file after open() ing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to create a file, use:

```
f =  open('Basic wx python window', 'w')
```

if you want to open a file for readding:

```
f =  open('Basic wx python window')
```

But recommand to use with statement,:

```
with open('Basic wx python window', 'w') as f:
    ...
```

Comment: None of those seem to work, could it matter that I'm on a mac. I tried another way to open files using subprocess but I wanted to get familier with the open command.

Comment: I think I misunderstood, sorry about that.